# Cumulative SUM Next 3days

Tags: sql-server

I have data in SQL Server that it has target values. I'm trying to sum target value next 3 days for every day. I add monthly data every the first day of the month.

I tried to join the same table DateAdd function but it is working  to slow

```
 select  
  DayId, 
  PODId,
  ProductCode,  
  TargetGsv,
  Sum(TargetGsv)  Over( order by  DayID ,PODId rows between current row   and 2 following) as D3TargetGsv
  from  [table name]
  order by DayId,ProductCode desc
```

here is my sample data. The last column is the one that I want to do . last 10 days results

```
PODId   ProductCode  DayID        TargetGsv   TargetLitre   D3TargetGsv
56  67717823     2019-07-31   341.115     32.0706       341.115
56  67717823     2019-07-30   341.115     32.0706       682.23
56  67717823     2019-07-29   341.115     32.0706       1023.345
56  67717823     2019-07-28    0           0            682.23
56  67717823     2019-07-27   341.115     32.0706       682.23
56  67717823     2019-07-26   341.115     32.0706       682.23
56  67717823     2019-07-25   341.115     32.0706      1023.345
56  67717823     2019-07-24   341.115     32.0706      1023.345
56  67717823     2019-07-23   341.115     32.0706      1023.345
56  67717823     2019-07-22   341.115     32.0706      1023.345
56  67717823     2019-07-21    0           0           682.23
```

Is there anything

Comment: Question is not clear, Please provide expected output ..

Comment: Not that it would increase performance, but I wonder if this the OVER could use a PARTITION.  F.e. `SUM(TargetGsv) OVER (PARTITION BY PODId ORDER BY DayID DESC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

Comment: thank you I'm going to try this query